# What does negative value for potential energy mean?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, conventions

What does negative value for potential energy mean and which is more stable in potential energy for example -3000 or -4000? I read that it doesn't mean anything and the values of the energies are usually negative.

Comment: As in nature only energy differences matter, the point of zero energy is arbitrary. You might want to read some discussions about 'gauge invariance'. I also recommend these threads: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17082/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560722/

Comment: A negative potential energy of two attracting particles means smaller the resulting mass of the compound system with respect to the non interactibg particle system.

Comment: thanks for replying so particle which has higher potential energy is more stable than which has lower potential energy ?