# What does negative electrical energy signify?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

When we derive the formula for potential energy caused by the torque of a dipole in uniform electrical field we get $U = -pE \cos \theta$. And my textbook tells me that the when the dipole is kept parallel to the electric field, the angle made is zero $\cos\theta = 1$, thus the potential energy $U$ is $-pE$. The textbook also tells me that this is the minimum energy attained by a dipole in external electric field ($U = -pE$) and the configuration is stable. But since energy is a scalar quantity, it isn't supposed to have direction, So, what does the negative symbol signify?

Comment: It's always about energy differences, the sign is nothing to worry about. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560722/is-it-possible-for-a-system-to-have-negative-potential-energy?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/608493/what-does-negative-value-for-potential-energy-mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolute values of the potential energies of systems do not have any physical meaning. It is the *change* in potential energy that has a physical meaning.

When the potential energy of a dipole system is derived, the following approach is used:
$$U_f - U_i = \int dW = \int_{\theta_i}^{\theta_f} \tau\cdot d\theta$$
$$U_f - U_i = pE \int_{\theta_i}^{\theta_f}\sin\theta\cdot d\theta,$$
and consequently, $$\boxed{\Delta U= -pE(\cos\theta_f - \cos\theta_i).}$$

From here, a *reference* configuration is chosen for the dipole system such that **$U_i = 0 \ \text{at}  \ \theta_i = 90^{\circ}$**, purely for convenience, which gives the formula $U = -pE\cdot\cos\theta$.

Naturally, any positive or negative signs arise only due to this choice of convention and do not possess any meaning as such.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So negative PE signifies the decrease in potential energy from the chosen reference configuration right?

Comment: Yes. For example, $U = mgy$ is a formula obtained only when you define $U = 0$ at $y = 0$ (usually the ground). If you go below $y= 0$, $U$ is negative only relative to the chosen configuration of $y = 0$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much :)